# Saving embedded OLE Object (Excel workbook) to file in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I am trying to save an embedded OLE Object (Excel workbook) from my current/open workbook to a location on the user's PC. This OLE object is a template/dashboard that gets populated during the execution of the macro.

The macro first tests if the file exists on the user's C drive.

If it does exist, it opens that file and sets a workbook variable to this newly opened workbook. This works in both Excel 2010 and Excel 2013.

Where the user does NOT have the file saved to their C drive, the macro opens the OLE object to save it to drive. The macro then points back to that location and opens the file. The code works in Excel 2013, however in Excel 2010, the macro crashes Excel when I try to save the file to the drive. If I run the macro in break mode, saving works, it is only during run-time that there is a crash.

Could there be a possible use of DoEvents or Application.Wait here?

Some things that I've noticed:

1. The crash does not generate any error code. It simply gives "Has stopped responding".
2. I've tried multiple versions of .SaveAs fileformat:=52 vs .SaveCopyAs. Both methods produce the same crash in 2010.
3. The OLE object opens as "Worksheet in", it would be nice if this opens in a new workbook. I'm thinking this crash could be related to how the object is opened as a "Worksheet in" rather than it's own workbook.

Code:

```
Dim uName As String
Dim fName As String
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim sumWB as Workbook
Dim cbrWB as Workbook

Set cbrWB = Workbooks("PreviouslySet")    

uName = Left(Environ("AppData"), Len(Environ("AppData")) - 16)
fName = uName & "\OTPReport"  & ".xlsm"

If Dir(fName) = "" Then

    Set oEmbFile = cbrWB.Worksheets("CBRDATA").OLEObjects("OTPReport")
    oEmbFile.Verb 0

    For Each wbk In Workbooks
        If InStr(1, wbk.Name, "Worksheet in", vbTextCompare) > 0 And InStr(1, wbk.Name, Left(cbrWB.Name, Round(Len(cbrWB.Name) / 2)), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Set sumWB = Workbooks(wbk.Name)
        End If
    Next wbk

    With sumWB
        .Activate
        .Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        '==ISSUE EXISTS HERE==
        .SaveCopyAs (fName)

        .Close
    End With
    Set sumWB = Nothing
    Set sumWB = Workbooks.Open(fName)
Else:
    Set sumWB = Workbooks.Open(fName)
End If
```

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer rather than editing your question.

Comment: Oh, will do. I guess my Stacketiquette is poor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the actual embedded COM object instead of the default action that `.Verb 0` gives you.

OLEObjects expose a reference to the underlying object if they are being administered by a COM server (it's the `.Object` property).  In your case, since you have an embedded workbook, it's just a `Workbook` object like any other `Workbook` object you'd encounter in VBA.  All you should need to do is call `.SaveAs` on it:

`oEmbFile.Object.SaveAs fName`

Then you can simply skip the rest of the gymnastics related to trying to find it in your current Excel server.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've updated my code to use the oEmbFile.Object.SaveAs fName    as you have suggested. I've tested it out on both 2010 and 2013. Both versions react in the same way. Upon calling that line, a new workbook is created in my list of projects titled "BookN.xlsm" (N=some number). This workbook is not visible in my list of applications. It is only visible in the VBA Project explorer. I cannot call an activate on it to make it visible. I can confirm that a file does get saved to the "Fname" location correctly, but when I try to open that file, it opens up another "hidden" wbk

Comment: Doing some more testing here.. these hidden workbooks have something to do with the Window(I).Activate. I think there is something to work with here..

Comment: Hi Comintern, I've updated the post and given you credit for the answer. The solution seems to be working well in both excel versions. I do have one question however. Why is it that when using the oEmbFile.Object.SaveAs fName, we get a file saved to our fName location that defaults to having an unopened window when opened. In order to open that file, you must call a "Windows("workbookName").Activate" to make the window visible.

Comment: @Citanaf - That's a good question, and I'm not sure that I know exactly why.  I *suspect* that the new copy of the file "inherits" the state of the embedded workbook, and that embedded sheets don't have an active window. Just a guess more than anything - I've never thought to check if an embedded sheet even *has* a window.

Comment: I'm inclined to believe your suspicion. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Posting my solution here to show what seems to be working in both 2010 and 2013. This solution was developed with the help of user COMIntern. I will give credit for this solution to his answer.

Updated code w/ explanation:

```
Dim uName As String
Dim fName As String

uName = Left(Environ("AppData"), Len(Environ("AppData")) - 16)
fName = uName & "\OTPReport" & ".xlsm"

If Dir(fName) = "" Then
    Set oEmbFile = cbrWB.Worksheets("CBRDATA").OLEObjects("OTPReport")
    oEmbFile.Object.SaveAs fName

    'For some reason a new workbook named "BookN" (n = to some integer) is created when 
    'saving our embedded file to C. To counter this, I close the most recently opened workbook.
    Workbooks(Workbooks.Count).Close

    'When opening this workbook, the file shows that it is opened, but the window is not activated. 
    'We must use the name of the file and call activate to get it to show up in our active windows.
    Set sumWB = Workbooks.Open(fName)
    Windows("OTPReport.xlsm").Activate
Else:
    'same explanation as above
    Set sumWB = Workbooks.Open(fName)
    Windows("OTPReport.xlsm").Activate
End If
```