How to have a button to download all object in Excel
I have the excel file, I will insert many objects in the file.

The file has no specific format (.pdf .xlsx .word etc)
I want to add a button, when I press the button, all the object will be downloaded to the local path.
However, it has error message:

Run-time error '438':
Object doesn't support this property or method

Could anyone help to fix the error message.
Thank you guys
This is my VBA code:
Sub DownloadObjectFiles()
   Dim obj As OLEObject
   Dim path As String
   Dim i As Integer

   path = "C:\Downloads\" 

   For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

       For Each obj In ws.OLEObjects

           obj.Copy
           With CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
               .Paste
               .ExportAsFixedFormat 2, path & "Object" & i & ".pdf"
               .Close
           End With
           i = i + 1
       Next obj
   Next ws
End Sub`


DId you check https://danny.fyi/embedding-and-accessing-a-file-in-excel-with-vba-and-ole-objects-4d4e7863cfff or https://stackoverflow.com/a/39458287/6600940

Hi Storax, I checked and tried, but I still not sure how to solve my problem.
Could you please kindly provide some solution? Thanks a lot!!

I think it would be best you post what you tried and where you got stuck.
